# Python Nested For Loop Counting Backwards

Tags: python, for-loop

This is probably a simple problem, but I am trying to created a nested loop that would count up from 0 to 9 in the outer loop, and in the inner loop, start from the value (or index. They are the same in this case) of the outer loop and count backwards.

Here's an example:

```
i= 0
k= 0

i= 1
k= 1
k= 0 

i= 2
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0

i= 3
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
```

I got this far:

```
x = range(0,10)
for i in x:
    print 'i = ',x[i]
    for k in x:
        print 'k = ', x[i::-1]
```

Obviously, the code above doesn't do what I want it to do. For one, the second for loop doesn't start from the value of i in the outer loop and counts backwards. For another, it doesn't print a new `k =` for every new value.

Comment: I assume here that `k[i::-1]` is really `x[i::-1]`, isn't it?

Comment: Or you can do `range( i, -1, -1 )` to get  `[ i, i-1, i-2, ...., 2, 1, 0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be like this:

```
x = range(0,10)
for i in x:
    print 'i = ',x[i]      
    for k in x[i::-1]:
        print 'k = ', k
    print("\n")
```

The result is:

```
i =  0
k =  0


i =  1
k =  1
k =  0


i =  2
k =  2
k =  1
k =  0


i =  3
k =  3
k =  2
k =  1
k =  0


i =  4
k =  4
k =  3
k =  2
k =  1
k =  0


i =  5
k =  5
k =  4
k =  3
k =  2
k =  1
k =  0


i =  6
k =  6
k =  5
k =  4
k =  3
k =  2
k =  1
k =  0


i =  7
k =  7
k =  6
k =  5
k =  4
k =  3
k =  2
k =  1
k =  0


i =  8
k =  8
k =  7
k =  6
k =  5
k =  4
k =  3
k =  2
k =  1
k =  0


i =  9
k =  9
k =  8
k =  7
k =  6
k =  5
k =  4
k =  3
k =  2
k =  1
k =  0
```

Basicly, `x[i::-1]` should be in the for not in the print.

Comment: And `x[i]` > `i`, as you're there

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: `x` is a range of integers. In this case there's no sense in using `x[i]`, because `i`... is `x[i]`! Same as you're printing `k` straight, instead of `x[k]`

Answer (score 2):

What about just manipulate it with `print` function?

```
i = 0
k = 0

while True:
    print (i)
    print (k)
    if 1<k: #tricky part
        print ("\n".join([str(h) for h in range(0,k+1)][::-1]))
    print ("")
    i += 1
    k += 1
    if i == 10:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. If you are new to the world of python you can take some inspiration from this example where I use list comprehension.

`list = lambda k: [ [ i for i in reversed(xrange(j+1)) ] for j in xrange(k+1) ]`

**Note**: If you are using python 3 "*xrange*" is changed to "*range*"

Now call:

`list(3)`

And you'll see that the result is similar to what you are looking for.

`[[0], [1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0]]`

Comment: The asker wants to print the results, not put in a list. But nice answer!